# Issues getting Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1) Camera Megapixels with this function

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm getting the camera megapixels with this function:

```
private String getCameraMegapixels(Camera cam){
        Camera.Size size;
        size = cam.getParameters().getPictureSize();
        DecimalFormat localDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");        
        return localDecimalFormat.format(size.width * size.height / 1000000.0D);            
    }
```

It works fine for front and back camera in all the phones i tested but but in Galaxy nexus. In galaxy nexus something is going wrong because i'm getting that the camera (front and back) haves 0.1 megapixels....

Is something wrong with galaxy nexus and the way to get megapixels?

PD: Galaxy Nexus Android version is 4.2.1

Comment: I'm seeing size.width = 320, size.height = 240 for both front and back cameras. Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1, Cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to get the maximum supported megapixels, you could simply check each of the `Camera.Size` in `cam.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes()` and choose the highest `height*width` of them.